# ionic 2 firebase uploading image

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, firebase-storage, ionic3

I am creating a chat application with ionic 3 and firebase. In the profile pic section I am allowing the user to upload an image. The image is uploading well and is visible in my firebase storage, but every image that is uploaded by the user is of 4 bytes and preview is not available hence, the profile image does not set to new image.
Kindly help on how to fix this
Kind Regards,
Aditya

```
Imagehandler.ts(That uploads file to firebase)
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileChooser } from '@ionic-native/file-chooser';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path';
import firebase from 'firebase';
/*
  Generated class for the ImghandlerProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ImghandlerProvider {
  nativepath: any;
  firestore = firebase.storage();
  constructor(public filechooser: FileChooser) {
  }

  uploadimage() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.filechooser.open().then((url) => {
          (<any>window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(url, (result) => {
            this.nativepath = result;
            (<any>window).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.nativepath, (res) => {
              res.file((resFile) => {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(resFile);
                reader.onloadend = (evt: any) => {
                  var imgBlob = new Blob([evt.target.result], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
                  var imageStore = this.firestore.ref('/profileimages').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
                  imageStore.put(imgBlob).then((res) => {
                    this.firestore.ref('/profileimages').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                      resolve(url);
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        reject(err);
                    })
                  }).catch((err) => {
                    reject(err);
                  })
                }
              })
            })
          })
      })
    })    
     return promise;   
  }

}
```

user.ts(that handles all user methods)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase';

/*
  Generated class for the UserProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class UserProvider {
  firedata = firebase.database().ref('/users');
  constructor(public afireauth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  adduser(newuser) {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afireauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newuser.email, newuser.password).then(() => {
        this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
          displayName: newuser.displayName,
          photoURL: ''
        }).then(() => {
          this.firedata.child(this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid).set({
            uid: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.uid,
            displayName: newuser.displayName,
            photoURL: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-4eadd.appspot.com/o/chatterplace.png?alt=media&token=e51fa887-bfc6-48ff-87c6-e2c61976534e'
          }).then(() => {
            resolve({ success: true });
            }).catch((err) => {
              reject(err);
          })
          }).catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        })
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
    })
    return promise;
  }
passwordreset(email) {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(() => {
        resolve({ success: true });
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
    })
    return promise;
  }
updateimage(imageurl) {
      var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
              displayName: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.displayName,
              photoURL: imageurl      
          }).then(() => {
              firebase.database().ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({
              displayName: this.afireauth.auth.currentUser.displayName,
              photoURL: imageurl,
              uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
              }).then(() => {
                  resolve({ success: true });
                  }).catch((err) => {
                      reject(err);
                  })
          }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
             })  
      })
      return promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwr9dCsJAt3kYTZhY0p1UTFnUVU

Comment: The above is the link to my code for more clear insight that handles my profile pictures requests